# Extracting Max Datetime From a Series of Lists with Datetime Elements

Tags: python, datetime

I have a series of datetime lists (with lists of length 0, 1, 2). Here is a sample of the output:

```
[datetime.time(21, 0)]
[]
[datetime.time(23, 59), datetime.time(0, 45)]
[datetime.time(0, 45), datetime.time(23, 59)]
[datetime.time(23, 59)]
[]
[datetime.time(22, 0)]
```

I want the list to be either length 0 or 1; effectively, I want to return only the max value within the lists of 2 to shorten them to length 1. The above sample output would instead come out as:

```
[datetime.time(21, 0)]
[]
[datetime.time(23, 59)]
[datetime.time(23, 59)]
[datetime.time(23, 59)]
[]
[datetime.time(22, 0)]
```

Is there some sort of datetime max statement that would return the highest time value between two (or several) list (datetime) elements?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since `datetime.time` has the comparison operations defined, you can use the usual operations like `<`, `max`, ...

```py
new_timeseries = timeseries.apply(
    lambda datetime_list:[max(datetime_list)] if datetime_list else []
)
```